# Java EE real world open source applications

Tags: java, open-source, jakarta-ee

What are good Java EE real world (not like learning projects like PetStore) open source  applications? In particular I'm looking for examples of using ORM (JPA-Hibernate), Spring (IoC, transaction managment, security) in a real world environment

ps a good example what I'm looking for - [ASP.NET starter applications](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/) (for .net platform)

Comment: Nice examples behind the link by the way. Unfortunately nothing like that "flashy" comes to mind in the "boring" Java EE world ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alfresco uses Spring/Hibernate.  I believe OpenNMS does as well.

Answer (score 3):

The Java EE 6 homepage has several samples: [Java EE 6 Sample Applications](http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/code/). Further there's the [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) which gives you the possibility to compose a kickoff Java EE application together yourself.

**Update**: I realize that you're rather looking for an overview of all "3rd party" open source Java EE based ecommerce/business/CMS systems. You can find pretty complete overviews at [Java-Source.net](http://java-source.net/). For example all [ERP-CRM systems](http://java-source.net/open-source/erp-crm) and [CMS systems](http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems).

Comment: BalusC, they are real-world? (i.e. they can be used for some business cases without modification?) I'm not looking for a bunch of examples that solves some particular task. I'm interested how business problems can be solved using all this technologies together

Comment: Yes, I now see what you mean. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself looking for a substantial demonstration of JPA. I came accross a CRM tool called "BroadLeaf Commerce", built on Spring and JPA. It's available on github, personally I've found it to be an invaluable learning tool with respect to JPA.

http://www.broadleafcommerce.org/